# Angular Material Table Collape Dynamtic Like Jquery Datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I am not sure if there is any way to do like this with Angular Material Table.

[image]

My current Angular Material Table is ugly on mobile.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not by default but you can use Table with sticky columns by adding the sticky directive to matColumnDef.
Sticky columns will allow you to scroll horizontally across all the columns with out breaking the UI.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-columns

Comment: would you mind showing me how or example ? I want something like expand/collape like JQuery datatable.

Comment: scrolling is not User Friendly to me.